# Задача: сколько сегодня записей

Tags: алгоритм

Условие задачи:
(не буду описывать условие задачи разными метафорами, скажу сразу как есть и что надо).

Есть один сайт (сторонний) и я пишу небольшой userscript на JavaScript. На сайте есть определенная информация (таблица) вида

```
#NUMBER; DATA; DATE
```

таблица ну уж очень большая, поэтому на одной странице вмещается всего 20 строк, а дальше уже нам нужно перейти по ссылке *"следующая страница"*, чтобы читать таблицу дальше. Таблица отсортирована по дате. То есть таблица начинается так

```
#1 полезная информация 17.08.2013 22:34
#2 полезная информация 17.08.2013 22:35
#3 полезная информация 17.08.2013 22:44
```

Итак. Мне нужно узнать, сколько записей в таблице сделано за сегодня!

- Что мне известно: сегодняшняя дата.
- Что функция должна вернуть:
     количество записей в таблице за
     сегодня.

В среднем за день в таблицу вносится около 4000 записей, но иногда меньше, иногда совсем не вносится ничего, а иногда и все 10000. В среднем за месяц - редко больше 6500 в день.

У меня ничего нет кроме начальной страницы и ссылок на последующие страницы (можно перейти на любую страницу сразу). Я делаю ГЕТ запрос на первую страницу и если я там нахожу сегодняшнюю дату (в таблице), то смело могу делать запрос на вторую страницу - все в порядке, таблица еще "свежая". Дальше, дальше, оп - даты нет - значит сегодняшние записи закончились. Делаю запрос на страницу назад и смотрю номер строки, в которой все еще написана нужная дата. Так я получаю ответ на мучающий меня вопрос - сколько сегодня добавили записей.

В чем вопрос. Как оптимизировать алгоритм? Я не хочу делать запрос на каждую страницу!!! Я пытался шагать через одну страницу, пытался использовать половинное деление.. Что я только не пытался - толком не вышло ничего. Напишите, пожалуйста, псевдокод. Дальше я сам разберусь. Просто помогите придумать алгоритм.

Спасибо.

Comment: mysql? не select count(*) from mytable where date(mydatecolumn)=curdate() ?

Comment: Сайт вообще не мой. Нет доступа к базе дынных! :)

Comment: А в чём проблема с половинным делением? По идее, вам нужно (1) найти последнюю страницу (она или доступна сразу, или придётся шагать с удвоением), (2) половинным делением найти первую страницу, на которой есть информация для нужной даты, (3) шагать от этой страницы до момента смены даты или исчерпания страниц.

Comment: Если в среднем 4000 записей в день, то шаг 3000 хорошо подойдет для определения страницы на которой уже другая дата